# Remove a string from php

Tags: php, string, joomla, replace, substr

I use this php code in joomla to get prefix languages en es fr de ..

```
$doc->addCustomTag('<<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/'.$lang = str_replace('en', '', substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0, 2)).'/pages.html"/>');
```

And this code remove the suffix en to replace it with nothing that what i wanted but the result give me a page like this http://www.mysite.com//pages.html
how do i remove the / speacialy for the en prefix

Comment: Remove the $lang = part and see if that works.

Comment: i removed the lang part and still have //

Comment: What does JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag() return?

Comment: it return the current language prefix : en fr de es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
$doc->addCustomTag('<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/'.str_replace('en/', '', substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0, 2) . '/').'pages.html"/>');
```

Comment: ty but i didnt work all that code i had are inside a $doc->addCustomTag so when i add a long code it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it in two steps:

```
<?php
$lang = str_replace('en', '', substr(JFactory::getLanguage()->getTag(), 0, 2));
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/'.$lang.'/pages.html';
$url = str_replace('//', '/', $url);
?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wanting to remove the `/` specifically for the `en` prefix, something like this could be done:

```
$lang = & JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang =  $lang->getName();
$lang = substr($lang, 0, 2);
if($lang !== 'en') // check if $lang is English
    $lang .= '/'; // append a slash
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/'.($lang == 'en' ? '' : $lang.'/') . 'pages.html';
```

Comment: ty bro but it gave me errors maybe because of $doc->addCustomTag